# Google Chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is there way to run native C/C++/Obj-C within a google chrome extension, The official page says extension are like other web pages, as i see it there is no way except Native Client(NaCl). Is this technically possible.

Comment: NaCL:PEPPER is the new sandbox plugin since NPAPI will be depreciated very soon. To test drive NaCL, make sure you have a new browser (v10) and visit about:flags and enable NaCL.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you are looking for [NPAPI plugins](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/npapi.html). Do not take lightly the warning, however:

#### NPAPI is a really big hammer that should only be used when no other approach will work.

Why does your extension need C/C++/Objective-C, exactly?

---

#### Re: OP comment

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828217/bonjour-discovery-in-javascript-maybe)!

Comment: Trying to enable bonjour so i can share data on the network, is this possible technically?

Comment: @user: that's definitely an interesting thought. I'm sure that it is _technically_ possible. If it helps at all, what you're actually looking for is a [Zeroconf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_configuration_networking) implementation; Bonjour is just Apple's implementation of the protocol.