# Is it possible to use websockets without knowing the IP address of the server in a LAN?

Tags: android, ios, html, websocket, bonjour

I would like to know if it is possible to establish a WebSocket connection between an HTML 5 app running on a browser and a websocket server running in a electronics custom board. The board uses an ATSAMS70 and WINC1500.
Both will be always running in the same local area network and I would like to cover the majority of internet capable devices: MAC/Windows machines, iOS, Android.
Some kind of method like Bonjour or service discovery would be great if HTML 5 had one...

Comment: It is possible to establish a webSocket connection between any HTML5 app and any standard webSocket server as long as you know either the IP address or the DNS name of the webSocket server.

Comment: So, I would need to somehow assign a DNS name to the service provided by my custom board. I would need a server running in the LAN for that, right?

Comment: Local service discovery like Bonjour provides is not yet a standard part of browser implementations.  There are some ways to do it using a browser plug-in such as [Bonjour Discovery in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828217/bonjour-discovery-in-javascript-maybe), but that's not something you can depend on across the broad array of devices you list.  If the web page comes from a local web server,  then the local web server could do the discovery and the web page could use ajax to ask the local web server for discovery info.  Otherwise, it's a local DNS or local server solution.

Comment: When a web browser connects to any hostname, whether that is a web server or a web socket, the browser's standard DNS lookup logic is used to find the IP. In a LAN scenario, the router provides DNS for connected devices, so the browser should be able to find the IP of the board if it has a hostname. If the board does not have a hostname, check if your LAN router has an option to assign its own hostname for the board's IP/MAC.